# Border renders when using CSS Sprites

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to use CSS sprites to reduce the number of HTTP requests on page. I want the these images to render without borders.

As best I can tell I have configured the CSS correctly, yet I am experiencing the render issues below (note: The Google logo is intentionally clipped):

[image]

As you can see, all the browsers still render a border. Also, IE and FireFox render 'broken link' type icons as well.

The HTML used in this example is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      img {border:none}
      img.css_sprite { background:url("http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png") -20px -10px; height:24px;  width:100px; border:none;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="css_sprite"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure it must be something simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short, you need to visit this site: http://validator.w3.org/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The border belongs to this:

```
<img class="css_sprite"/>
```

It's a border drawn by the browsers due to a missing image. Here you don't specify any `src` so the browsers add the border and missing image graphic instead.

Change the `img` to some other element instead like `div` or `span` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent solution just put a blank transparent image (preferably 1x1 png) within the src  elements...:) as the image is transparent it will not visible at all src does not go blank and your purpose is solved...

Comment: How does this help the OP display 'nav_logo29' without a border?